# i am trying to get max id in my table and concatenate it with current date with - sign

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table name Student and have attribute name RegistrationNo and i am trying to get max Registration id from table and concatenate it with current date year..like if registration no is 45 and current year is 2018 so after concatenation it looks like 45-2018..

i use + operator to concatenate them but it add up the year and max registration num..

```
select (isnull(max(Reg),0)+1) + '-'  + CONVERT(int,Year(getdate())) as NextCode
from Admission;
```

Comment: One option would be to use `concat()`: `concat(max(reg), '-', year(getdate()))`.  Why are you adding 1 to the `max(reg)` though?

Comment: i am adding one because if there is no value of RegNo in table then it will show max 0+1=1 in my textbox of window form..

Comment: thanks..using ur code my problem is solved now

Comment: You can use `isnull(max(reg), 1)` instead of adding 1.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but you can more simplify it as :

```
select max(Reg) + '-' + cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) as NextCode 
from Admission;
```

However, `concat()` would do shorthand :

```
select concat(max(Reg), '-', year(getdate())) as NextCode 
from Admission;
```

Comment: i just want to concatenate my max (reg) value with current year value and make it one single value as Nextcode to add in my textbox...... like if 45 is max(Reg) and current year is 2018 then it must look like this 45-2018 in my textbox

Comment: On this case, the latest query from Yogesh Sharma works well.